# Notify user once database value is changed by continuously polling in background

Tags: c#, sql-server

Notify user once database value is changed.

I have to design in system in which user can create tickets and each ticket will have creation datetime and threshold timespan.

So as soon as  `currentdatetime - creatindatetime > threshold` is reached I have to notify it to user.

I have a class `Ticket`:

```
class Ticket
{
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public string TicketName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Threshold { get; set; }
}
```

In the database in `Ticket` table I will have these columns:

```
 TicketId, TicketName, CreatedDate, Threshold, LastNotificationSent
```

I thought of using a Windows service which will poll every 2-3 seconds and send all ticket information which are expired to the user via mail and update database column `LastNotificationSent`.

Main criteria we have to notify user as soon as soon as ticket is expired.

If we poll windows server every 2-3 seconds we will have many db calls which I have to avoid.

I am looking for any alternative.

Comment: What's your database engine?

Comment: You should use something like firebase, or a realtime database engine store, to notify clients that are connected. Also: If the tickets are going to be expiring at certain times, do you need to poll the database that often? Why not just grab everything expiring in the next few minutes, and display them as they expire.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz its Sql Server

Comment: @darkking The best thing to do with that information is [edit] your question and add the relevant tag, so the right people see it. In this case, Pablo has already given the relevant answer, so I'll do it for you, and for the benefit of other people in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft SQLServer as I guess you are, you should use [*Query Notifications*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server). It's exactly what you are looking for.

[Here's a code sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events) in C# you could use as base for your implementation.